# UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage returns nil only on RAW images

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having an issue whereby images that were taken by a Sony digital camera and transferred to my phone return nil when I try to save the image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. It returns an image for any image taken on my iPhone or downloaded from the Internet. Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

allowsEditing is set to false.

```
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {


    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) //5

    var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage //2

    let previewVC:ImagePreviewViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PreviewVC") as! ImagePreviewViewController
    previewVC.imageToCrop = chosenImage!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(previewVC, animated: true)

}
```

**UPDATE**
I discovered that this issue relates to my iCloud Photo Library sync and I selected a raw image (.arw) instead of JPEG. The raw images return nil